# Word 2013-create button/hot key to highlight select phrases

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, highlighting

At my job I'm currently skimming through long documents and highlighting whenever a figure or table is called out. It always appears between parenthesis, for example: (Figure 7-8,5) or (Table 2-2, 26). Is there a way to create a button or hot key to automatically highlight these in any given document? If not is there a fast way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go into Find and Replace, enable wildcards,
and search for `\(Table [!\(\)]@\)`. 
You can highlight it by setting “Replace with” to Highlight. 
Then repeat with `\(Figure [!\(\)]@\)`.